# When do I collect my money '...as I pass Go'?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I was playing Junior Monopoly yesterday. The, er, grown-ups disagreed (!) over precisely when you collect your £2 pocket money.

On the board itself the instruction is "...***Collect £2 pocket money as you pass Go***".

The rule leaflet says "***Every time you pass GO, collect £2"***.

My question is this.  In Junior Monopoly, when a player lands on GO (i.e. does not 'pass' GO but stops on the GO square) do they collect £2, ***or*** do they collect their two pounds only once they have passed GO (i.e. on their next turn).

Note that this question relates to JUNIOR Monopoly.  The adult version is very clear on this subject.  Although the adult version has a similar instruction on the board ("*Collect £200 as you pass Go*"), the adult rules say players be given £200 by the banker (i.e. do not have to 'claim the money') every time their token "*...either lands on or passes over GO, while going in the direction of the Arrow*".  The Junior version requires players to keep more alert to their financial entitlements!

Comment: Not an answer, but does the interpretation make any difference in play? You have no way to spend the money on Go, do you?

Comment: Yes @JamesMcLeod, it does!  When you land on GO you think "collect my money".  By the time your turn comes round again it is surprisingly easy to have been distracted and forget to claim your money before you shake the dice.

Comment: Then logic suggests payment be made when you land on the square - the goal is to have fun, not to punish the inattentive.

Comment: Please can you spell out your logic !

Comment: My logic is that it is unduly onerous to have to remember to ask when you leave the square, so payment should be made when you land upon it.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - Junior Monopoly DOES explicitly penalise the inattentive (it is a game you can lose!).  My question is not about whether a game play is unduly onerous or fun, but about what you understand by the phrase "...as you pass GO"!

Comment: And that is why I did not post an answer.

Comment: The instructions are unclear, so it's up to the players to negotiate an answer among themselves.  Things like this cannot be settled by appealing to prescriptivist interpretation of English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

The [US instructions](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monojr.pdf) state:

> GO!: Every time you pass GO!, collect $2 from the Bank.
>
> **Don’t forget to collect, because if you do, you’re out of luck!**

(their emphasis).

That to me suggests that it's when you ***PASS*** Go, not when you land on it. As per your point in the question, it's also clear that the onus is on the player to remember and request the money, it's not up to anyone else to remember. It also cannot be backdated.

I doubt that the concept of the game is meant to change somewhere mid-Atlantic, even if the wording has done at some point.

---

Conversely, if you think that this is harsh, you could do whatever everyone else seems to do with all variations of Monopoly, and have your own house rules... if you decide that it's £2 for landing ***ON OR AFTER***, then that's the rule; if you decide that it's only ***AFTER***, then so be it. So long as everyone knows the rule(s), then it's fair.

EDIT

The UK instructions you quote use the phrase ***as** you pass Go*. In this sense, as [means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?s=t) *at the same time that; while; when* - *as I was going to St Ives*, and all that. So, strictly, this means *while you are in the process of passing Go*. I suppose you could dig into that in a literal sense and conclude that the process of passing always includes landing on, whether it's a single die roll (i.e. counting forwards and landing on the space in transit) or a double one (landing and then rolling again later). In which case, landing on Go is simply part of the process of passing, and is thus as valid as simply tromping through.

But I'd go with the house rule myself, and just decide :)

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, the US rubric you quote does not feature the phrase used in the UK version "...as you pass GO".  How would you interpret this '*as*' ?

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted. The context of the US instructions indicates that *remembering to collect* is part of the game. My only quibble would be that *pass* in this context has the idea of *leave*, which is consistent with reminder - i.e. if you land on GO, collect the money at the start of your next turn.

Comment: @Lawrence - thanks for that comment - I don't disagree; where I had pause, though, was in the minutiae of *when* do you 'pass' something - at what point does it go from 'going to pass' to 'having passed'. Passing is, in itself, a continuous state. And then my brain melted, so I surrendered...

Comment: @ProfYaffle You're welcome. Consider the triple (approach, arrived, passed). In the course of each token's own progression, it passes GO when it leaves GO.